# heroku sqlite 1.3.6 issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

im trying to deploy my app in heroku but after installing the other gems it rails me this error

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2vzrh01g333bs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2vzrh01g333bs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:floating-journey-3614.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:floating-journey-3614.git'
[led@localhost djors]$ yum install sqlite-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

i checked`yum install sqlite-devel` but its already installed i tried google but nothing comes to me an answer i found issue in `1.3.6`  issue thanks in advance

```
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-09-23 patchlevel -1) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1
     - /home/led/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
```

my gem file

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'time_diff'
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'
gem 'activeadmin' , '0.4.3'
gem "formtastic", "~> 2.1.1"
gem 'validates_overlap'
gem "nifty-generators"
gem 'thin'
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"
end
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'bourbon'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: This problem is almost always because you are using a gem that requires sqlite.

Comment: hi are you saying with this? `gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"` i just found this on the other post and people are saying that it is working do you have any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your **validates_overlap** gem here :

https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap/blob/master/validates_overlap.gemspec

It has a `s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<sqlite3>, [">= 0"])`

Comment: so are you saying that validates_overlap gem is not compatible to heroku? sorry im new in rails :(

Comment: I don't know this particular gem, but from what I can see on github, the answer is no. You can try submitting an issue to the gem creator.

Comment: Glad it helped! This gem is not very complicated, all the code you need is in https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap/blob/master/lib/validates_overlap/overlap_validator.rb so maybe you could simply copy/paste it...